# Decompressing zip files with accents

Tags: java, parsing, zip, diacritics

I'm using a Java mechanism to extract zip files. The mechanism works fine if there is no files in it with accents on title. Since I'm from portugal, chars like ã, ç, õ, é, etc. are usually used in my language. If any of this chars are in the filename, an IO exception occurs.

```
while (zipFileEntries.hasMoreElements()) {
    ZipEntry entry = (ZipEntry) zipFileEntries.nextElement();    
    File destFile = new File(unzipDestinationDirectory, currentEntry);
    File destinationParent = destFile.getParentFile();

    // create the parent directory structure if needed
    destinationParent.mkdirs();

    // extract file if not a directory
    if (!entry.isDirectory()) {                 
        BufferedInputStream is =
            new BufferedInputStream(zip_file.getInputStream(entry));
        int currentByte;                
        byte data[] = new byte[BUFFER];

        // write the current file to disk
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(destFile);                  
        BufferedOutputStream dest = new BufferedOutputStream(fos, BUFFER);

        // read and write until last byte is encountered
        while ((currentByte = is.read(data, 0, BUFFER)) != -1) {
            dest.write(data, 0, currentByte);
        }

        dest.flush();
        dest.close();
        is.close();
    }
```

It crashes on `while((currentByte = is.read(data, 0, BUFFER)) != -1)`

```
java.io.IOException: Stream closed
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.getInIfOpen(BufferedInputStream.java:134)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:218)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:258)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:317)
    at parsers.ZipParser.decompressZipFile(ZipParser.java:83)
    at poc.MainPOC.main(MainPOC.java:61)
```

Are you aware of any workaround to deal with this problem? Can I change the filename of a file inside a zip without decompressing it?

Answer (score 3):

Since Java 7, there is a way new construcor to `ZipInputStream`to specify a charset to use for the filename. See the documentation [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipInputStream.html#ZipInputStream%28java.io.InputStream,%20java.nio.charset.Charset%29).

So you would create your `ZipInputStream` with something like :

```
ZipInputStream zis = new ZipInputStream(new FileInputStream("your zip file"), Charset.forName("Encoding here"));
```

See [Charset](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/charset/Charset.html) to have a bit more informations about how to use it.

It will not change the way you are reading the file, so you will need another workaround to read the content. But for more information, see this answer [Java zip character encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12787489/2115680), you can probably re-use some of the code.

Comment: I checked the answer you provided and putting `Charset.forName("ISO-8859-1")` worked for french accent. TY

Answer (score 0):

I think you must set the encoding properly when you compress and decompress.  Did you make it UTF-8 when you created the ZIP file?  If not, I'd recommend trying it.

Comment: I'm not the one responsible for making the input zip file. I don't have any influence on how the zip files are created...

Comment: You'll have to find that influence or it won't work.  Perhaps you need to have a conversation with the partner that is creating them.

Comment: This isn't really an option :/  I will replace the java.util.zip by the Apache Commons IO lib.

Comment: Which uses - wait for it - the java.util.zip classes to do its work.