# Java zip character encoding

Tags: java, encoding, zip

I'm using the following method to compress a file into a zip file:

```
import java.util.zip.CRC32;
import java.util.zip.ZipEntry;
import java.util.zip.ZipOutputStream;

public static void doZip(final File inputfis, final File outputfis) throws IOException {

    FileInputStream fis = null;
    FileOutputStream fos = null;

    final CRC32 crc = new CRC32();
    crc.reset();

    try {
        fis = new FileInputStream(inputfis);
        fos = new FileOutputStream(outputfis);
        final ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(fos);
        zos.setLevel(6);
        final ZipEntry ze = new ZipEntry(inputfis.getName());
        zos.putNextEntry(ze);
        final int BUFSIZ = 8192;
        final byte inbuf[] = new byte[BUFSIZ];
        int n;
        while ((n = fis.read(inbuf)) != -1) {
            zos.write(inbuf, 0, n);
            crc.update(inbuf);
        }
        ze.setCrc(crc.getValue());
        zos.finish();
        zos.close();
    } catch (final IOException e) {
        throw e;
    } finally {
        if (fis != null) {
            fis.close();
        }
        if (fos != null) {
            fos.close();
        }
    }
}
```

My problem is that i have flat text files with the content `N°TICKET` for example, the zipped result gives some weired characters when uncompressed `NÂ° TICKET`.  Also characters such as `é` and `à` are not supported.

I guess it's due to the character encoding, but I don't know how to set it in my zip method to `ISO-8859-1` ?

(I'm running on windows 7, java 6)

Comment: You're viewing the precompressed and postcompressed files with the same editor correct?

Comment: @fvu: issue is with file content, not file names

Comment: Why are you using streams instead of writers/readers? Streams are not aware of characters or their encodings.

Comment: @Wug you are correct! actually it's a CSV file so i view the post-compressed file with Excel... :-/ So it's an Excel issue i presume

Comment: @Wug but as suggested by Dunes in his answer, adding ` Charset.forName("ISO-8859-1")` to my output writer resolved the problem (Excel shows the correct values)

Comment: Maybe this can help, its using ApacheCommons-compress library to fix JDK6 issues http://stackoverflow.com/a/20523390/185565

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are using streams which write exactly the bytes that they are given. Writers interpret character data and convert it to the corresponding bytes and Readers do the opposite. Java (at least in version 6) doesn't provide an easy way to to mix and match operations on zipped data and for writing characters.

This way will work though. It is, however, a little clunky.

```
File inputFile = new File("utf-8-data.txt");
File outputFile = new File("latin-1-data.zip");

ZipEntry entry = new ZipEntry("latin-1-data.txt");

BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(inputFile));

ZipOutputStream zipStream = new ZipOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(outputFile));
BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
    new OutputStreamWriter(zipStream, Charset.forName("ISO-8859-1"))
);

zipStream.putNextEntry(entry);

// this is the important part:
// all character data is written via the writer and not the zip output stream
String line = null;
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    writer.append(line).append('\n');
}
writer.flush(); // i've used a buffered writer, so make sure to flush to the
// underlying zip output stream

zipStream.closeEntry();
zipStream.finish();

reader.close(); 
writer.close();
```

Comment: thank you adding `Charset.forName("ISO-8859-1")` to my `BufferedWriter` resolved the problem.

Comment: Same here `ISO-8859-1` worked for **french** accent. TY

Comment: I could generate zip file without encoding problem in my case but I was not able to read European characters from generated zip file correctly. I used InputStreamReader with "ISO-8859-1" and it works fine. Anybody can find working code sample here https://gist.github.com/kairos34/75f782b029540e60c2f3b69e5166588e

Answer (score 4):

Afaik this is not available in Java 6.

But I do believe that http://commons.apache.org/compress/ can provide a solution.

Switching to Java 7 provides a new constructor that that encoding as an additional parameter.

https://blogs.oracle.com/xuemingshen/entry/non_utf_8_encoding_in

```
zipStream = new ZipInputStream(
    new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(archiveFile), BUFFER_SIZE),
    Charset.forName("ISO-8859-1")
```

Comment: the problem is with the output file not the input file, and as @Wug pointed it out in his comment, it's not the file but Excel that show the correct encoding i have no idea why..

Answer (score 0):

try to use org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipFile; not java's own library so you can give encoding like that:

import org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipFile;

ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile(filepath,encoding);